# Как сделать button louder при отправке http запроса на Angular

Tags: javascript, angular2, angular

Начал изучение angular, и решил узнать как можно сделать при нажатии на любую кнопку в моем приложении которая отвечает за отправку запроса на сервер что-то подобное

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Built-In-Loading-Indicator-In-Buttons-Button-Loader/

В интернете ничего не нашел так как скорее всего делаю поиск по неправильному запросу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кстати, всегда спрашиваю на собеседованиях как показывать лоадер на каждый HTTP запрос и скрывать его после того, как пришел ответ или ошибка. Если нужно показывать глобальный лоадер (например крутилку где-то справа вверху экрана), то это решается с помощью перехватчиков.

Для первой задачи нам нужны сервис-состояние, перехватчик и компонент верхнего уровня. Создаем сервис, который будет просто кешировать `boolean` значение:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LoadingService {
  private loading$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  public isLoading(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loading$.asObservable();
  }

  public showLoader(): void {
    this.loading$.next(true);
  }

  public hideLoader(): void {
    this.loading$.next(false);
  }
}
```

Нужен перехватчик, который будет перехватывать HTTP запросы, показывать лоадер перед отправкой запроса и скрывать после того, как пришел ответ или ошибка:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private loadingService: LoadingService) {}

  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loadingService.showLoader();

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.loadingService.hideLoader())
    );
  }
}
```

`finalize` очень удобная штука, которая вызовет переданный колбек в случае успешного комплита потока либо ошибки. Регистрируется перехватчик в корневом модуле следующим образом:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: LoadingInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }
]
```

Также нам нужен компонент, хотя это может быть не компонент, а вообще обычный `img`:

```
<img src="/path-to-loader.gif" *ngIf="isLoading | async">
```

Не забудьте инжектить сервис в компоненте:

```
constructor(private loadingService: LoadingService) {}

public get isLoading(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.loadingService.isLoading();
}
```

---

Если стоит задача показывать лоадер возле кнопки, то здесь нужен переиспользуемый компонент, который входным параметром будет принимать свойство `loading`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: `
    <button>
      <img src="/path-to-loader.gif" *ngIf="loading">
      {{ text }}
    </button>
  `
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input()
  public text: string = null;

  @Input()
  public loading = false;
}
```

Только это грозит тем, что придется дублировать код в компонентах с входным параметром:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-button text="Подтвердить" [loading]="loading"></app-button>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public loading = false;

  public submit(): void {
    this.loading = true;

    this.someService.makeSomeHttpRequest().pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.loading = false;
      })
    ).subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Вроде как понял, а вроде как и нет, просто только над этой задачай сегодня часа 4 просидел пока крыша не поехала, завтра попробую и если что отпишусь, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Я могу тебе где-то в привате написать, телиграм или ещё что-то, ты из Харькова?)